# Trying to assign a numerical value to represent the value of the work we do

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a table where I make it easier for someone who works with me to assign photo sessions to my colleagues (we are photographers) based on how many people are in the group, where they are staying, and if they show up and purchase the photos or not.

So my idea is something like `"sold"x"people"x"place"` - where `"sold"` is assigned a value of either 0 or 1, depending on if they bought their photos or not, `"people"` is assigned a number - 1,2,3 or 4, for either `"individual"`, `"couple"`, `"family"` or `"group"`, respectively, and `"place"` is assigned either a value or 2 or 3 based on how much people staying at a certain place spend on average, so I have Bliss, Mayan, Luxxe with a multiplier of 2, 2 and 3, respectively.

I'm trying to use a combination of VLOOKUP and COUNTIF, but I can't seem to get it right... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sold | Luxxe | Family means Value is 1x3x3 (9)
Sold | Mayan | Group means Value is 1x2x4 (8)
Not Sold | Bliss | Couple means Value is 0x2x2 (0)
```

There is a sheet where all the data is, and there is a sheet where I just see the results, where I just fill in what everyone did and I get the point amount without having to do the calculations manually and where I can maybe get a sum at the bottom.

Input:

[image: Input]

Data:

[image: Data]

Also, this is what I am using at the moment, but I can't seem to make everything have the value I assigned it.

Current table:

[image: Current table]

Comment: Help us help you.  Please [edit] the post and include a mock up of the raw data, how desired inputs will be, and the expected output for the inputs using the mocked up data table.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I did some edits and added some images just for you guys to see what I mean. I appreciate your patience!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and adapt the following formulae:

```
=XLOOKUP(Z10,$AG$3:$AG$4,$AH$3:$AH$4) * XLOOKUP(AB10,$AA$3:$AA$5,$AB$3:$AB$5) * XLOOKUP(AC10,$AD$3:$AD$6,$AE$3:$AE$6)
```

OR

```
=INDEX($AH$3:$AH$4, MATCH(Z10,$AG$3:$AG$4,0)) * INDEX($AB$3:$AB$5,MATCH(AB10,$AA$3:$AA$5,0)) * INDEX($AE$3:$AE$6,MATCH(AC10,$AD$3:$AD$6,0))
```

[image]

**Note:** `XLOOKUP` is only available on EXcel365.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it. Seems to work :-)

Comment: @AndreiMihalache Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers). If and only if your question has been answered, you can mark the answer as solved.